# How to push my router link as login link when the token expired using react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

How to do pushing my router link to /login when the token expired?. Right now when my token expired but the link url still on the last history that I stopped. I don't know what this problem called but I put my goal and current output.

**Goal: If the token expired the router link will be push on /login not on the last Link that I stop.**

**Library Use:**

1. Redux Toolkit
2. React Router Dom

**Imports:**

```
//router
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useHistory  
} from "react-router-dom";


//components
// import Header from './components/Header';
import MainLayout from './components/MainLayout';

//not found
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';

//unaunthenticated user
import Login from './pages/Login';

//authenticated user
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import CustomerPayor from './pages/CustomerPayor';
```

App.js File:

```
function App() {

  let user = useSelector(selectUser);
  let history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div className="App" >
        {!user ? (<Login />) : (
          <Router>
            <MainLayout userProfile={user}>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/customer_payor" exact component={CustomerPayor}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
                  </Switch>
            </MainLayout>
          </Router>
        )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**As you can see here the token already expired and the page return to the component of login but my link is on customer_payor**

[image: Current Output]

Comment: Check the [auth flow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) demo and see if that helps straighten you out.

Comment: What is checking for the token expiration in your redux store while the app is running in order to update state and trigger the component to rerender so the selector can pull the updated `user` state and conditionally render the correct UI?

Comment: I used redux persist for storing the dispatch details and for checking of expiration of token. I used this condition. if(401 === error.response.status){
                dispatch(logout())
                localStorage.clear();
            }

Comment: No, I meant *after* your app loads and presumably checks if the token is expired when populating state.... later, how are you checking the token is still valid? In other words, when the token expires how are you invalidating your user/authentication state?

Comment: I used the let user = useSelector(selectUser); and check  {!user ? (<Login />) : all the components.

Comment: That's not a token expiration check though. I suspect you either need to set up some polling interval somewhere near the root of your app to periodically check if the token is expired, or better yet, when your app loads initially, capture the token expiration and set a timeout to update your `user` state to "log them out".

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can use [Redirect](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect):

```
<Route exact path="/">
  {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
</Route>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this is not working for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a check in the `useEffect` of the parent state provider to decrypt eg. jwt token and if it's expired you log the user out.

Then you use the `useLocation` hook from react router to do `location.push('/login)` afterwards